# Link tag just changes the url but not render the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to learn next js routing and encountered an error.

Every time I click the Link tag it just changes the url from "localhost:3000" to "localhost:3000/sample"
but it doesn't display the "Hi" on my sample.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
const Lnkz = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link href={"/sample"} as={'/sample'} >
                <a>CLICK ME</a>
            </Link>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Lnkz
```

and here is my sample.js file that displays "Hi" only.

```
export default function Sample() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hi</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

My entry file.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Lnkz from './Lnkz'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div>

      <Lnkz />

    </div>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

NOTE: I already tried to do this but it doesn't work too.

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
const Lnkz = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link href="/sample" as='/sample'>
                <a>CLICK ME</a>
            </Link>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Lnkz
```

Here is my directory

[image: directory]

EDIT: Added the code I also tried before and added screenshot of my directory.

Comment: Also include snapshot of your directory, next js routing is based on that

Comment: Hi @Solvenc1no, I added the directory. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Not directly related to the issue (which like @Solvenc1no mentioned is probably related to casing) but you should not have your components inside the `pages/` folder. That folder should only contain your pages.

Answer (score 2):

I think after seeing your directory, the problem is in the casing. Only include "as" if you are using an older version of next.js, more on that [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link).

try this or change your file name to sample.js (with small 's')

```
  <Link href={"/Sample"}>
        <a>CLICK ME</a>
  </Link>
```